# Problemas VPN L2TP Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, vpn

acudo a vosotros porque tengo un quebradero de cabeza con el tema de la configuracion VPN L2TP en windows server 2012 R2, os pongo en situacion.

Actualmente tengo una vpn PPTP configurada y totalmente operativa , pero mi mayor interes es dejar de usar ese modelo de conexion  pasarme a L2TP.

Por una lado e verificado que las reglas en el firewall  de windows esten operativas , e abierto los puertos en el router (1701 UPD , 4500 UPD y 500 UP) redigiriendo todo el trafico a la ip de mi servidor 192.168.1.51 , pero el mayor problema radica al realizar la conexion desde el exterior porque no se me conecta , ahora si realizo la conexion a nivel de red desde la maquina cliente apuntando a la ip arriba mencionada se conecta a la perfeccion , pero cuando la realizo desde el exterior (Otra localizacion) me da el siguiente error

[Error VPN Conexion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUYXF.png)

Por otra parte e verificado que en el lado del servidor las configuracion y la calve compartida para la conexcion esten correctas ya que si estubieran mal me daria error a la hora de conectar a nivel de red local.

Alguna idea delo que puede estar succediendo y como solucionarlo ?

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.....

Solucionado......Muchas gracias a todos , a continuacion dejo la solucion que me ayudo a resolver todo:

Paso Nº 1:
Cambiar una clave de registro que viene desactivada por defecto en Windows. Hay que cambiarla: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent Y creamos un nuevo «Valor de DWORD (32 bits)» llamado: AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule Y le damos el valor 2.
Paso Nº 2:
Segunda Calve a Cambiar en la siguiente ubicación HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy Y pulsaremos con el botón derecho sobre la clave «IPsecThroughNAT», y cambiaremos el calor también a 2. , en el  caso de no existir dicho registro crearemos uno , clic derecho  «Valor de DWORD (32 bits)» lo nombramos como «IPsecThroughNAT» y posteriormente damos clic derecho encima y seleccionamos cambiar valor y ponemos el 2
Paso Nº 3:
Reiniciamos el equipo.
Paso Nº 4:
Creamos una conexión VPN Nueva

•   Proveedor de VPN – Windows
•   Nombre de conexión – Elegimos un nombre
•   Nombre de servidor o dirección – IP estática del servidor al que vamos a conectarnos
•   Tipo de VPN – L2TP con clave compartida
•   Clave previamente compartida – Clave IKA
•   Usuario y contraseña de VPN.
•   Guardamos la configuración.

Paso Nº 5:
Configuramos el adaptador de la conexión VPN (Windows 7,8,10)

1. Nos dirigimos al panel de control y Seleccionamos la opción <> y damos clic, posteriormente nos saldrán varias opciones de las cuales seleccionaremos <>, una vez dentro de la opción seleccionada en el panel de la izquierda pulsaremos sobre la opción <<Cambiar la configuración del adaptador>>. Una vez accedido encontraremos todos nuestros adaptadores incluido el de la conexión que hemos creado, lo seleccionamos y pulsamos clic derecho , des las opciones que se desplegarán a posterior seleccionamos la opción << Propiedades >> y nos vamos a la pestaña de Seguridad, recordar verificar que los parámetros este igual que en la imagen que adjunto a continuación.
2. Una vez realizados las comprobaciones pertinentes daremos clic sobre el botón Configuración Avanzada y se nos abrirá una ventana donde deberemos tener seleccionado la opción de calve compartida, tal y como aparece en la imagen. Recordar que debéis poner la clave secreta que previamente se os ha informado
3. Una vez realizado lo antes mencionado nos dirigimos a la opción de funciones de red, seleccionamos el protocolo IPV4 y damos clic en el botón propiedades , se nos abrirá una opción , seleccionamos la opción usar las siguientes direcciones de servidor dns
   Establecemos en el Servidor Primario la siguiente DNS: 8.8.8.8 y en el secundario la dns 8.8.4.4 y pulsamos aceptar para que se nos guarden los cambios
4. Realizado este punto desmarcamos el protocolo de internet versión 6 (TCP/IPV6) para que no nos genere conflictos a la hora de conectarnos tal y como aparece en la imagen

Una vez completado todos los pasos la conexión se realizará de manera exitosa….

Comment: creaste la regla para port forwanding en el router? verificastes si tu proovedor te asigno una ip statica?

Comment: @Bryro Si , tengo una relga echa en el frewall apuntando a la ip del servidor y tenemos una ip estatica contratada

Comment: Si os sirve e encontrado la solucion , os la paso